# react-navigation 5 and Formik handle submit not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, formik, react-navigation-v5

I was following this [example](https://snack.expo.io/@nyashanziramasanga/header-interaction?platform=android&name=header%20interaction&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%40%5E5.8.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%40%5E5.9.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%40%5E5.2.16%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%40%5E5.7.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%40%5E5.9.0%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.0.1%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E2.15.1&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F5.x%2Fheader-interaction.js) on the react-navigation docs and the handleSubmit from the Formik form mainly on `onPress={handleSubmit}` isn't handled.

```
React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title='Update' />,
    });
  }, [navigation]);

  const handleSubmit = (values: IUser) => {
    setLoadingVisible(true);
    updateAccountDetails(values);
    setUser(values);
  };
```

```
 <Form
          initialValues={{
            id: user.id,
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            address: user.address,
          }}
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          validationSchema={accountDetailsValidationSchema}
        >
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `<Form/>` component in react-native formik
https://formik.org/docs/guides/react-native#the-gist

also you might want to add button component with layoutEffect to separate component as a child of

```
 <Formik
  initialValues={{ email: '' }}
  onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  {({ handleChange, handleBlur, handleSubmit, values }) => (
   <View>
     <TextInput
       onChangeText={handleChange('email')}
       onBlur={handleBlur('email')}
       value={values.email}
     />
     <HeaderButton onSubmit={handleSubmit} navigation={navigation}/>
   </View>
 )}
```

add layoutEffect to `<HeaderButton/>`

```
const HeaderButton = ({ handleSubmit, navigation }) => {
  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
   navigation.setOptions({
     headerRight: () => <Button onPress={handleSubmit} title='Update' />,
     });
  }, [navigation, handleSubmit]);

   return (<></>);

}
```